# Back Orders for ERP: data model references?

Tags: database-design, business-logic

My question is: **do you know of any real good reference (book, web) for ERP database design** ?

I have built an ERP using Sql Server as a back-end.  There are different types of Client documents (there are also Supplier Docs):

1. Order  -- impact: Back-Orders (BO)
2. Delivery Note (also used for returns, with negative quantity)  --impact: BO, Stock
3. Invoice       --impact: accounting only
4. Credit Note   --impact: accounting, BO

BO tracking is very complex, and involves tracking links between different documents: imagine a returning customer that has ordered several times 10 units of reference X: which delivery fills which order ? If there is a credit note for 5 units of reference X, does it have an impact on BO ? For which order ? (these are just examples)

Answer (score 1):

[The Data Model Resource Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471380237).

Comment: Looks nice, thanks. Could not evaluate yet: only volume 3 is available in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

There are several pattern data models (industry standard data models) that cover this topic.  In addition to Len Silverston's books (mentioned in another answer), there are pricey proprietary models (Teradata, IBM, etc.) and an industry one from the Association for Retail Technology Standards ([www.nrf-arts.org)](http://www.nrf-arts.org).  It is free to members of the association.

It covers a great deal of the complexity of commerce - shipping, ordering, back orders, customer orders, invoicing, payments, etc.